# Resize the root partition of Ubuntu 20.04 with an lvm partition

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, lvm

I installed ubuntu 20.04 server recently, and used lvm for partitioning. Here is the output of the command lsblk:

```
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                       7:0    0 29.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/8542
loop1                       7:1    0   55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1880
loop2                       7:2    0 71.3M  1 loop /snap/lxd/16099
loop3                       7:3    0 29.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/8790
loop4                       7:4    0 55.3M  1 loop /snap/core18/1885
loop5                       7:5    0 70.6M  1 loop /snap/lxd/16922
sda                         8:0    0  1.8T  0 disk 
├─sda1                      8:1    0    1M  0 part 
├─sda2                      8:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0  1.8T  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0  200G  0 lvm  /
sr0                        11:0    1 1024M  0 rom  
sr1                        11:1    1 1024M  0 rom
```

I am using Nextcloud that is storing information just in the root, is there a way to transfer the sda3 part to the / partition?

Or should I do a fresh install of the system, and if so, can someone point me on how to use all the 1.8Tb for the root partition?

Comment: Check my answer here https://askubuntu.com/a/1417735/513874

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 LTS, not all disk space was allocated during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269493/ubuntu-server-20-04-1-lts-not-all-disk-space-was-allocated-during-installation)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution provided in the link Riad shared worked for me. However, I'm summing up the steps here in case the link breaks:

1. use `df -h /home/` or `df -lh /` to check your filesystem space and name. There you can see if there is still space, the name of the mount, etc.
2. use `vgdisplay <thevgname>` to display the volume name and details. There you can see VG size (total size), Allocated (used) and Free space. The free space hints on how much you could expand your partition.
3. use `lvextend -L +2G /thename/of/filesystem` to extend the size the partition. In this example it was increased by 2Gb... edit this part according to your needs.
4. the, use `resize2fs /thename/of/filesystem` to actually expand the used space.
5. check again with `df -l` to see the changes done.

**Addendum:**

Doing similar stuff (resizing, etc) I stumbled with another case, where `cfdisk` and `lsblk` did show that my /sda3 had enough size, but happened that my Physical Volume (PV) still needed to be resized.

For that [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/583544/201132) answer helped me, which suggested to do:

```
sudo psv
```

To find the PV name (like /dev/sd3), and then resize it using `sudo pvresize /dev/sda3`. Modify according to your needs and volume names. I then was able to continue with the steps listed on this answer and proceed with `lvextend` and later `resize2fs`

Comment: Use `lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/volgroup/logvol`to extend the partition with the left free space.

Answer (score 5):

Finally, I found it by checking this post: https://www.linuxtechi.com/extend-lvm-partitions/

The idea is to extend the lvm partition to take advantage of the empty space.

Comment: Thanks for the Link! Although it's better if you posted here the steps in case the link breaks.

Comment: The "Use Your Default Free Space" from this link also works: https://packetpushers.net/ubuntu-extend-your-default-lvm-space/